# How to enable and disable the dropdown values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Here is script

```
$('#first').change(function(){

    switch ($(this).val())
    {
        case '1st':
            $('.1st').show();
            $('.2nd').hide();
            break;

        case '2nd':
            $('.1st').hide();
            $('.2nd').show();
            break;

        case '3rd':
            $('.3rd').hide();
            $('.3rd').show();
            break;

        case 'none':
            $('.1st').show();
            $('.2nd').show();
            break;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZVSu/3/

In first Dropdown, `All, Edit, Delete, Modify` is given. I need like this..

1. If I click `All` in first dropdown, it should display `All,051,052,111,123,222,444,555,777,888,911,999` in second dropdown.
2. If I click `Edit` in first dropdown, it should display
   `All,051,052,111,123,222,444,555,777,888,911,999` in second dropdown.
3. If I click `Delete` in first dropdown, it should display only
   `All` in second dropdown.
4. If I click `Modify` in first dropdown, it should display only
   `All` in second dropdown.

I am having few doubts here.

Comment: `Is it possible in jquery?` you already used jquery

Comment: Yes used jquery only. But couldnt able to get the right one. Could you please help me with the code?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#first').change(function(){
    $('#second option').hide(); // hide all options
    switch ($(this).val())
    {
        case '1st':
            $('.1st').show();
            break;

        case '2nd':
            $('.2nd').show();
            break;

        case '3rd':
            $('.3rd').show();
            break;

        case 'none':
           // show all options except for delete and modify
           $('#second option').not('.3rd, .2nd').show();
            break;
    }
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZVSu/7/)

Comment: There is one problem here. If I click All in first dropdown, it is displaying All three times ..Can you please take a look?

Comment: This is because you have two more 'ALL' option at the bottom for class 2nd and 3rd.     <option class="2nd" value="val13">All</option>
    <option class="3rd" value="val14">All</option>

Comment: That was given for Delete and Modify in first dropdown..But getting three All options in first dropdown!

Comment: And if you don't wan to repeat 'ALL' for Delete and modify then use only one 'ALL' option and make it hide and show.

Comment: Ok, in that case you have to omit these two 'ALL'. see here http://jsfiddle.net/8ZVSu/7/

Comment: For the first time, it was selected All as Default. So, in this condition, it is showing three All. When I switch over to Edit and come back to All in first dropdown, it is showing as expected! Problem with first time when it loads..

Comment: then hide it when page loads using $('.3rd, .2nd').hide(); see this http://jsfiddle.net/8ZVSu/9/

Comment: One help. Why the values remains in Delete and Modify? select cams  and select any other values in second dropdown
then select rc07 and see the value (value that was selected in cams)in second dropdown
why this happens? instead of All

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55747/discussion-between-bhushan-kawadkar-and-user3107196).

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZVSu/11/)** 
 In your context your first drop down value ,second drop down class has relation b/w each other .so using `this.value`to get selected element

```
$('#first').change(function () {

    if (this.value == "none") {
        $("#second option").not(".2nd,.3rd").show();
    } else {
        $("#second option").hide();
        $("." + this.value).show();
    }


});
```

Comment: There is one problem here. If I click All in first dropdown, it is displaying All three times ..Can you please take a look?

Comment: same problem remains balachandran :(

Comment: @user3107196. actualy i did'not understand what you were asked . now i updated my post pls check it

Answer (score 0):

Two way：

1. you need 4 second select,  show one of them when you change the first dropdown.
2. use js template generate the second dropdown dynamic.

You **can't** show or hide `<option>` direct in chrome.